# GetVersionEx() depreciated, what should be used instead for Windows 7/8/10/11?

Tags: windows, winapi

How can I get the Windows OS version, revision and build number ('10.0-19045') from ISO C code (not C++, not C#)?

I tried to replicate it via GetVersionEx(), but that is deprecated, and I cannot find suitable example code.

Comment: `RtlGetVersion` or `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers`